# Match text in parentheses only if followed by certain char

Tags: regex

My test string: `(MATCH) X (MATCH)[1] "(NO MATCH)" (NO MATCH)X (MATCH) X`
I want to match the text in the parentheses (with the parentheses), but only if the parentheses are followed by a whitespace or a `[`.

I currently have this **[regex](http://rubular.com/r/mwaXsA2kcq)**, but it is greedy and i don't know how to make it lazy.

How do i make my regex expression lazy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :

```
(\([^\)]*?\))(?=[\[\s])
```

**[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/oGYQnr5aVi)**

**EXPLANATION :**

[image]